# Bulk Loader in cassandra : String as row keys in cassandra

Tags: java, cassandra, bulkloader

I have done with bulk loader with key_validation_class=LexicalUUIDType for new row with the help of this [code](http://www.datastax.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/DataImportExample.java) but i have changed my **key_validation_class=AsciiType** or **key_validation_class=UTF8Type** in order to make **string as row keys**

```
  create column family Users1
  with key_validation_class=AsciiType
   and comparator=AsciiType
  AND column_metadata = [ 
  {column_name: timestamp1, validation_class: AsciiType}
  {column_name: symbol, validation_class: AsciiType}
  {column_name: Bid_Price, validation_class:AsciiType}
  {column_name: Ask_Price, validation_class:AsciiType}
  ];
```

i have tried all possible changes to code in order to make row keys as string type but getting an error or even without **usersWriter.newRow** not able to write into sstable

```
  while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null)
    {
         if (entry.parse(line, lineNumber))
        {   
            //usersWriter.newRow(uuid);
            usersWriter.newRow(String.valueOf(lineNumber));
            usersWriter.addColumn(bytes("symbol"), bytes(entry.symbol), timestamp);
            usersWriter.addColumn(bytes("timestamp1"), bytes(entry.timestamp1), timestamp);
            usersWriter.addColumn(bytes("Bid_Price"), bytes(entry.Bid_Price), timestamp);
            usersWriter.addColumn(bytes("Ask_Price"), bytes(entry.Ask_Price), timestamp);
        }
        lineNumber++;
    }
```

getting an error as expected it is only taking **ByteBuffer**

```
 usersWriter.newRow(String.valueOf(lineNumber));
                       ^
 required: ByteBuffer
 found: String
 reason: actual argument String cannot be converted to ByteBuffer by method invocation  conversion
```

Any help to make string as row keys in sstable for the above column family definition.thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [Using the Cassandra Bulk Loader](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/bulk-loading):

> The methods of the simple writer expect ByteBuffers for the row key,
>   column name and column value. Converting data to bytes is your
>   responsibility; this is the *raison d’être* of the bytes() method.

So you should write the code as follow:

```
usersWriter.newRow(bytes(String.valueOf(lineNumber)));
```